# How to force only 1 DNS server for home user?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, opendns

I am trying to have only one DNS server selected for lookups but it keeps forwarding my lookups to 2 others in a differnet location much closer to my geolocation. That is precisely what I am trying to avoid.

I set it at the `Internet Protocol IPv4 > General > Use the following DNS server address`

Is the issue that the DNS I have selected is forwarding my DNS lookups to another DNS server? If so, do I only need to find such DNS server that won't redirect?

How are some websites detecting what DNS servers did I use to visit them?
Edit: Looks like this might explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721731/is-it-possible-to-detect-visitor-dns-server

Comment: what website is telling you what DNS server you are using?

Comment: https://whoer.net/#extended this one

Comment: I think I solved it I just don't know why it worked. I changed the DNS settings again to 1.1.1.1 from cloudflare. Now the DNS server IP is not visible there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You apear to entirely misunderstand how DNS works.

DNS does not redirect requests. A nameserver will ask its upstream nameservet for answers it does not know.  As a general rule, a minimum of 2 nameservers are required for any domain name - most domain names have more then one.

An authorative ( ie nameservers associated with a domain) know the IP address of the nameserver that queried it, and based on this source IP address they can make a very educated guess where the querying nameserver is, and thus roughly where the end device is. There are lots of DNS servers, so lots of IPs and geographic hints.

FWIW, nameservets like Googles 8.8.8.8 are special in that it actually comprises of lots of clusters of nameservers which are routed differently based on where you are.

Using a VPN or a non-clustered nameserver remote to you [if you can find one that will accept queries from you] can "force" different answers.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself poorly. I know DNS servers "serve" as phonebooks for domains and IP pairs. My issue was that after I have selected a specific DNS IP for my system, a site like https://whoer.net/#extended still saw 2 others DNS servers pop up and I didn't understand why. So I was guessing that the DNS I have selected forwarded my lookup to a different DNS server closer to my real location.

How does that website know which DNS did my browser contact to get their IP? Did DNS also tell it to the website? I am not aware of any headers that would leak this information.

Comment: That does not show any DNS servers when I go there. I would not put to much faith in it. The url, Im guessing, made some dns lookups and used the nameservers that it saw - which were likely internal/nat related  addresses associated with the cluster - ie your single namesetver is likely actually more then 1 nameserver sharing a sinhle address, much like 8.8.8.8 does.

Comment: I changed the DNS settings again to 1.1.1.1 from cloudflare. Now the DNS server IP is not visible there anymore, but I don't know why exactly, what was happening before. Every other information that that website got, I know how they get it but don't know how they knew DNS IP.

Comment: If you set 8.8.8.8 for your PC, one or more googles DNS IPs should show up on that website for you too.

Comment: well, its also notable that that page shows information that it can't discern from network traffic, like LAN IP, by using javascript to gather additional info from the browser.

Comment: @FrankThomas correct, but how do they know my DNS resolver information? That can't be from JS.